# Definition of Perfect hash function

Tags: algorithm, hash

Is a perfect hash function always bijective ? In Wiki "In mathematical terms, it is a total injective function" but it does not mean, that it is bijective.

Comment: A bijective hash function is called "minimal perfect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
According to wikipedia, "[a] perfect hash function for a set S is a hash function that maps [...] elements in S to a set of integers." [1] For such a function to be *bijective*, the size of `S` would have to be the same as the size of the set of all integers. *Injective* means that no two elements of `S` are mapped to the same integer, *surjective* would mean that every integer has an element in `S` that maps to it.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function